# use barebone Yii2 framework

Tags: yii2

I need to use Yii2 Rest and so I want to strip all JS filea and any "strip-pable" client side classed/resources. I couldn't find a way yet and [my ticket](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/14095) is yet to be answered. Any pointer is appreciated

**UPDATE:**

By stripping I mean not installing them at all. I want only to install the minimum possible of the framework files

Comment: Doesn't `RestAction` just return appropriate content (like JSON or XML) with no assets whatsoever? There's nothing to strip there.

Comment: sorry for confusion. I have updated what I mean

Comment: You could edit the framework's `composer.json` to remove things you don't need. But I don't really see the point.

Comment: thank you. The point is simple, I want as small footprint as possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have written lengthy documentation on how to do that in this [Pull Request](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/pull/14154). I will update when and if get merged